# Cannot use Percent (%) in a Lua pattern

Tags: lua

I have this line in a Lua script that crash my software every time:

```
fmt_url_map = string.gsub( fmt_url_map, '%2F','/' )
```

I want to replace all occurrences of `%2F` occurrences in a text to `/`.
If I remove the % , it doesn't crash.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`%` is a special symbol in Lua patterns. It's used to represent certain sets of characters, (called character classes). For example, `%a` represents any letter. If you want to literally match `%` you need to use `%%`. See [this section](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#5.4.1) of the Lua Reference Manual for more information. I suspect you're running into problems because `%F` is not a character class.

Comment: Those aren't regular expressions; they're patterns. There's a big difference between them, and the Lua documentation never calls them regexes.

Comment: You're right, my mistake. I keep forgetting that Lua lacks a alternation operator in patterns. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape the '%' with another '%'

```
fmt_url_map = string.gsub( fmt_url_map, '%%2F','/' )
```